# AngularJS back button default to open to last ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three buttons on a page and depending on which on you click a different set of tabs is shown.  Once you make a selection a reset button is available to clear your choice. In these tabs a user is able to make a selection and is then taken to a results page.  What currently happens is, if a user clicks back via the browser the default view is the three original buttons but what I would like is the default view to be the last tab they were in before sending off for results. Is there a clever angular way to handle this?

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2WZ12TKcHGXWmLhgD1vj

Buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Qualifications">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tab = 1; showSelectorTabs=true; showSelectorButtons=true">Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tab = 2; showSelectorTabs=true; showSelectorButtons=true">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button disabled="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tab = 3; showSelectorTabs=true; showSelectorButtons=true">Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tabs:

```
    <tabset ng-show="tab == 1">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </tabset>


    <tabset ng-show="tab == 2">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </tabset>

    <tabset ng-show="tab == 3">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </tabset>
  </div>
```

Comment: So u want to open the previous URL on click?

Comment: No just go back to this page from a results page with the tabs open as default and not the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicholas is right, but I did something like this recently without using ngRoute so I wanted a simpler way to accomplish it. In addition to your original issue, you might want to consider using ng-repeat because (based on your example), that would save you a lot of code. Like so:

```
<div class='btn-group' role='group' ng-repeat='button in buttons'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='buttonSelected(button)'>Button {{ button }}</button>
</div>


<tabset ng-repeat='tabset in tabsets' ng-show='tabset.name == selectedTabset'>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='tab in tabset.tabs' ng-class='{active: tab.active}'><a href='#{{ tabset.name }}_{{ tab.name }}'>{{ tab.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</tabset>
```

Like MichaelOryl mentioned, I'd also suggest moving some of that logic out of the view and into the controller. I added the scope objects called above in ng-repeat in case you're not already familiar with that.

```
$scope.buttons = ['One','Two','Three'];

$scope.tabsets = [
    {   name: 'One',
        active: false,
        tabs: [
            {name: 'Home', active: true, content: ''},
            {name: 'Profile', active: false, content: ''},
            {name: 'Messages', active: false, content: ''}]
    },{ // two more, same structure as first tabset }]

$scope.showSelectorButtons = true;
$scope.showSelectorTabs = false;
$scope.selectedTabset = 'None';
$scope.buttonSelected = function(selected){
    $scope.showSelectorButtons = false;
    $scope.showSelectorTabs = true;
    $selectedTabset = selected;
}
```

And finally, here's my take on the location. You'll notice I added unique identifiers to the hrefs in the view, then I use those to select the proper tab on page load. This is also off the cuff, so no promises but it would look something like this:

```
$scope.deepLink(url){
    if(url.indexOf('#') > -1){
        var hash = url.split('#')[1];
        var tabsetId = hash.split('_')[0];
        var tabId = hash.split('_')[1];
        var hashTabset = $filter('filter')($scope.tabsets, {name: tabsetId}, true);
        var hashTab = $filter('filter')(hashTabset, {name: tabId}, true);
        angular.forEach($scope.tabsets, function(tabset){
            tabset.active = false;
            angular.forEach(tabset.tabs, function(tab){ tab.active = false; });
        });
        hashTabset.active = true;
        hashTab.active = true;
    }
}

var url = $location.url();
$scope.deepLink(url);
```

Hope this is helpful, if you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider saving the current selected tab in either a cookie or in browser local storage.  You would only erase the value when appropriate (such as when the reset button is hit).  I believe this would cause the currently selected view to be the default, more or less, when the user comes back in due to hitting page refresh or the back button.

I've use [LocalStorageModule](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) with good success for app defaults and general settings.

Otherwise you might want to just use the generic [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) module.

You should probably change your ngClicks to call functions inside your controller, though:

```
ng-click="setTab(3)"
```

You'd then have something like this as a controller, calling in the localStorageService, for example.  This is off-the-cuff code - it probably won't run. I'm just trying to show you what I mean.

```
app.controller('SecretCtrl', function ($scope, localStorageService) {
  $scope.tab = localStorageService('defaultTab');
  if ($scope.tab == null) { $scope.tab = 0; }

  $scope.setTab = function(tabNumber) {
    $scope.tab = tabNumber;
    $scope.showSelectorTabs=true;
    $scope.showSelectorButtons=true
    localStorageService.add('defaultTab', tabNumber);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you're using ngRoute or something similar and actually triggering URL changes in your app.

Push the state of $scope.tab into the URL with $location.search(), and when your page first loads read the state of it back off the URL to initialize which tab is active.

Change your buttons to call a function on your controller:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showTab(1)">Button 1</button>
```

Function on your controller does the logic you previously had in the HTML, in addition it updates the URL to contain the current selected tab number:

```
function showTab(tabNumber) {
     $scope.tab = tabNumber; 
     $scope.showSelectorTabs=true; 
     $scope.showSelectorButtons=true;
     $location.search({tab: tabNumber});
}
```

When your page is first loaded, initialize the tab from the value in the URL if it's available, otherwise default to tab 1 or whatever you like:

```
$scope.tab = $location.search().tab != null ? $location.search().tab : 1;
```